# Restart JS function (endless scroll) when used in different pages, to avoid accumulated results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an **endless scroll JavaScript function** working fine for different pages when loading each page for the first time.

**The problem**: The function gets called again when visiting the other pages, resulting in duplicate repeated results (2x) for the secondly visited page's endless scroll, and 3x for the next one, and so on, when clicking the page's links, though it works fine when manually refreshing each page.

I can not move the JS code from each view, to the main Layout view because it requires other JS code running within each view.

**My question**: How can I refresh/clear the JS function upon visiting each page so it starts fresh? Or which alternatives do I have?

**This is the code** on each page with pagination:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
var isLoading = false;
var num = 2;
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
   if (!isLoading) {
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 1500) {
      isLoading = true;
        var newUrl = url.replace("page="+num-1, "page="+num);
        $('#loader').html('<img src="/assets/gmloader.gif" alt="loading..." />');
        setTimeout(function(){isLoading=false},1000);
        num++;
        return $.getScript(newUrl);
      }
    }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

I appreciate your help.